# a script working in greasemonkey on firefox but not working in tampermonkey on google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

this code working good on firefox but not working on google chrome
idk whats wrong with it
i have tried to use unsafewindow.$ but it didnt work too

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Torax New
// @namespace   ns-recaptcha
// @include     http://*.outwar.com/joinraid.php?*
// @include     http://*.outwar.com/formraid.php?*
// @include     http://demo.codeforgeek.com/google-captcha/
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// Main page:

window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event)
{
  if(event.data == 'submitForm'){
     var button = $("form input[type='submit']");  // submit form
     button.click();    
  }
}
// ==/UserScript==
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the devtools console? Is there just one `form` element on the page or there are many? Anyway, try `$('form').submit()` instead of `button.click()`.

Comment: @wOxxOm no errors in the devtools console and $('form').submit() didnt work

Comment: Hmm sometimes sites have different code for Chrome or Firefox so the message may not be sent at all. Try adding `debugger;` inside receiveMessage, open devtools, and reload the page: the debugger will pop up at that line.